# Loss functions for Regression task

Tags: regression, machine-learning, estimation, predictive-models, optimization

I am trying to understand the idea of Loss functions For Regression Task perfectly.

I have read many textbooks and articles, and I came up with questions related to this subject.

Several different uses of loss functions can be distinguished.

(a) In prediction problems: a loss function depending on predicted and observed value defines the quality of a prediction.

(b) In estimation problems: a loss function depending on the true parameter and the estimated value defines the quality of estimation.

(c) Many estimators (such as least squares or M-estimators) are defined as optimizers of certain loss functions which then depend on the data and the estimated value.

***Now, since my focus is on Loss Functions For Regression Task***

($y_i=\theta_0 +\theta_1x_{i1}+\dots + \theta_px_{ip} +\epsilon_i$ ,y is the dependent variable and x is the independent one)

My questions are as follows.

1. Should I write the loss function formula as a function of the parameter or of the variables ($\mathrm{L}\big(\theta,\hat\theta\big)$ or $\mathrm{L}\big(y,\hat y\big)$ )?
2. Should I consider the Loss function formula for one point or Not (with sums or not)?

**Note**

My thought is to introduce Loss function first and then to use the standard notation for all Loss functions (least square, absolute value and Huber Loss, Quntile Loss and so on).

**UPDATED**

I did the following but I am not sure

***L2 Loss***

$$ \mathrm{L}\big(\{y_{(i)}, \hat{y}_{(i)}\}_{i=1}^n\big) = \mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n\big(y_i-\hat y_i\big)^2;$$

***L1 Loss***

$$ \mathrm{L}\big(\{y_{(i)}, \hat{y}_{(i)}\}_{i=1}^n\big) = \mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n|y_i-\hat y_i|;$$

***Huber Loss***

$$
\mathrm{L}\big(\{y_{(i)}, \hat{y}_{(i)}\}_{i=1}^n\big) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2 & |y_i-\hat y_i| \leq \delta \\ \delta\mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n|y_i-\hat y_i|-\frac{1}{2}\delta^2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

***Log-Cosh Loss***

$$\mathrm{L}\big(\{y_{(i)}, \hat{y}_{(i)}\}_{i=1}^n\big)= \log[\cosh\mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)];$$

***Quantile Loss***

$$\mathrm{L}\big(\{y_{(i)}, \hat{y}_{(i)}\}_{i=1}^n\big) = \big[\tau \mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n|y_i-\hat y_i| + (1 + \tau)\mathrm{\sum}_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)\big].$$

Comment: In case a) I would use $y$ and $\hat{y}$. Notice that if you have a parametrized model $f(x;\theta)$ then this loss function also depends on theta as it becomes $L(y,f(x;\theta))$. In the Second case I would go for $\theta$ because it is intertwined in my mind with the parameter of a density/distribution/... Concerning the second question: I tend to use $l$ (lower case) for a single example and $L$ for the sum. This may be subject to personal style though...

Comment: @FabianWerner, what about case c?

Comment: I do not really understand case c but I guess that you actually mean $L(y, f(x;\theta))$ which is case a basically... So my guess is that there is actually no difference between case a and c... (?) Could you elaborate more on c?

Comment: @FabianWerner, ok which one is right for Least square for example? OR I should use something like you defined.

L($y,\hat y)$ = ($y-\hat y)^2$
OR
L($y,\hat y)$ = $\sum_i $($ y_i-\hat y_i)^2$

Comment: Actually, there is no 'y', it is just a placeholder in order to make it clear how the loss function looks like. In reality, we are given pairs of input vectors $x_i$ with 'true answers' $y_i$, i.e. $(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_N, y_N)$. Now for a single $y$ (that might or might not be one of the $y_i$) you specify the loss function with a lowercase letter, for example $l(y, \hat{y}) = (y - \hat{y})^2$. For the whole vector $\mathbf{y} = (y_1, ..., y_N)$ and a vector of predictions produced by some model $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = (\hat{y}_1, ..., \hat{y}_N)$ you use ...

Comment: $L(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{\hat{y}}) = \sum_{i=1,...,N} l(y_i, \hat{y}_i)$ (maybe up to a normalizing factor) and you optimize the model (in the parameter $\theta$) by minimizing $L(\mathbf{y}, (f(x_i;\theta))_{i=1,...,N})$.